# search_form_alter NOT BLOCK

Tags: search, forms

I was looking the insertion point to change some stuff in the search form. I manage to change the search block, but I can't find a way to do the same with the form I see in site.com/search/node I was 100% sure the hook should be function SearchformMod_search_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) { } But it seems like I'm wrong. If I try to use Theme developer I don't get any .tpl suggestion either. Any Idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook you want is [hook_form_FORM_ID_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_FORM_ID_alter/7):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_FORM_ID_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_search_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Code here
}
```

Alternatively you could use [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7):

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'search_form') {
    // Code here
  }
}
```

Comment: I was trying with something like this:
    function SearchformMod_form_search_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
 $form['#description'] = 'A DESCRIPTION';
}
But it doesn't work. The module is enabled. This is why I think the naming wasn't right. The form is the one I see in  /search/node

Comment: @aolba Try something like this instead: `$form['custom'] = array('#weight' => 0, '#markup' => 'Hello world!');`

Comment: Thank you for the help. This works and help me to keep searching in the right direction. Now I know I have the right name.

Answer (score 0):

The suggestion `MYMODULE_form_search_form_alter()` did not work for me. Drupal would not even call it. I ended up using:

```
function MYMODULE_form_search_block_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  // Code here
}
```